# Boost fusion as_map conversion behavior

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have the following two boost::fusion maps.

```
namespace bf = boost::fusion;
typedef bf::map<bf::pair<char,float>,bf::pair<int,double>> FusionMap;
typedef bf::result_of::at_key<FusionMap, char>::type localType; // fine

typedef bf::vector<bf::pair<char,float>,bf::pair<int,double>> FusionVec;
typedef bf::result_of::as_map<FusionVec> FusionMap2;
typedef bf::result_of::at_key<FusionMap2, char>::type localType2; // compile error
```

The first version works where as the second one gives me a compile error. My Compiler is VS2010.
Am I using the `as_map` function in a wrong way. I assumed that both maps should be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `::type`  missing at the end of `FusionMap2` définition.

Comment: How embarrassing. That took me a couple of hours and I did not see this.

Comment: +1 for admiration on being able to spot such errors. Bien joué !